# Notifying own server about an IAP from apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Is there anyway when an IAP is finished (buyer pays) that a server could be notified about the buying?

I need this to check IAP in the device agains my server data base to really check the user did not modify my IAP local data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to get notification to your server about IAP. Howver, After IAP succeeds in your code, you can post the success information to your server. Apple does not do it for you.

Comment: This is a bit of a problem. For some reason I could not be notified or before receiving the information something could happen (game shut down, etc...) and the buyer would loose what he bought. Don't really like how they have implemented this.

Comment: In that case you can check of the user has bought the iap during app startup. That is how Apple recommends using IAP

Comment: Do you mean quering apple servers?